# ios - How to auto-resize my view in storyboard? swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I try to auto-resize my view with auto-layout contraints, but I have some errors of Y-position missing. I can't understand what is wrong, I attached my Y-position to the top of the view.

Thanks for your help, here is the screenshot:

[image: Contraints error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you don't set a fixed height but, if you can, ALWAYS AVOID to put a fixed height for a view. For an app that can fit all screen is better to use different techniques. 
If don't want to set a fixed height on your view, you have two possible options:

1. **Give to the view a bottom constraint**. You should also set the distance between the bottom of your view and the screen (or another object below your view).
2. **Use stackview.** If you place your views into a stack view you will be able to autoresize the width and height of your views according to the screen dimension.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I needed, I'll use stackview. I avoided to put a fixed height for my view, but it produced errors and I think I needed to use stackview.

Comment: If you have never used stack views, at first it can be a little difficult understanding how to set all the possible parameters in order to reach the correct result, but it's an amazing powerful tool and I raccomand it to you for all your apps.

Answer (score 0):

You must give a height for the view or construct it's subviews in a way that gives it a height by hooking constraints properly from top to bottom

when you have a y position error it means top, bottom and height issue

and when x it means leading , trailing and  width issue

IF you want to create dynamic view drag a vertical UIStackView and give it a height and in runtime add items to it

```
 self.myStackView.addArrangedSubview(lbl)
```